# PyCharm Error Loading Package List

Tags: python, pycharm, pypi

I just downloaded PyCharm the other day and wanted to download a few packages. I'm using Windows 10 with PyCharm 2016.2.2 and python 3.5.2. When I go to the available packages screen it continually states:

> Error loading package list:pypi.python.org

I was just trying to download BeautifulSoup and I'm clearly missing something. Any help would be wonderful.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I am behind a corporate firewall and had this problem. All I had to do was go to `Settings/Appearance and Behavior/System Settings/HTTP Proxy` and check `Auto-detect proxy settings` and it worked.

Answer (score 10):

I got the same problem and solution was that I got some other repositories added to repositories manager. So, make sure that you don't have anything  extra then

> https://pypi.python.org/simple 
>    at Repositories

[image]
[image]

Comment: I deleted the lines accidentally listed in the "Manage Repositories" list and this fixed this error.

Comment: I forgot that I had added a repository incorrectly when trying to find a package that already came preinstalled, so deleting that solved my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

**Update PyCharm January 2020 Build**

If you are behind a proxy then

- Go to **File->Settings** search for proxy in the settings dialog
- Check *Auto-Detect Proxy Settings*:

[image]

Comment: Seems like a duplicate. What is the difference to the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50065680/5730279)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think you should use Default Preferences in File to install packages. Second, you should check "Manage Repositories" if there's any unavailable source.

Comment: Where are "Default Preferences in File" ? I can't find "Manage Repositories". Can you add screenshots to show the UI.

Answer (score 1):

File -> Settings -> Python Interpreter -> Add package -> Manage repositories -> Set only "https://pypi.python.org/simple", as told by @Jee Mok, works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue this past summer: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207207469-PyCharm-interpreter-can-t-find-new-packages

Have you tried pulling from http://pypi.python.org/simple/ ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You can improve your answer by adding some description about that issue. So that even the link will become broken, your answer will not be obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PyCharm on OSX behind a proxy you need to define proxy configuration the following should do the trick:

- Click on *PyCharm > Preferences > Appearance and Behavior > System Settings -> HTTP Proxy*
- Either select Auto-detect proxy settings
- Or select *Manual proxy configuration*

  1. Define the *Host Name* and *Port*
  2. and optionally *Proxy Authentication* if required
- Click *Apply*

Answer (score 0):

All the above solution did not work for me, I had to manually install the package using proxy:

```
pip install -U <package_name> --user --proxy=<your proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Corporate license, make sure you are connected to your corporate VPN