# Error loading package list: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: python, pycharm

I want to use Pycharm to download some packages. But when I open  **Pycharm** -> **Settings** -> **Python Interpreter** and click on the '+', it shows

> Error loading package list: Request failed with status code 404

[image]

Comment: This might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498602/pycharm-error-loading-package-list/50065680

Comment: sorry，I use the method to delete the 'https://pypi.python.org/simple'. But, it still show the error. And I add other source to the manage repositiores

Comment: "*And I add other source to the manage repositiores*" What other sources did you add? Please [edit] to show which repositories are now set on your Pycharm. Maybe one of the sources you added is leading to a 404.

Comment: I add ‘https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/’，‘http://pypi.douban.com/simple/’，‘http://mirrors.aliyun.com/pypi/simple/’ and ‘https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/’.